# how do i redirect from ItemDataBound event of repeater to another page by passing values

Tags: asp.net

i have a repeater control and on ItemDataBound event i want  fetch values in the repeater control and redirect to another page by passing those values as parameter.
i have written the following code

```
Protected Sub rptData_ItemDataBound(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

        Dim content As String = ""
        Dim url As String = ""
        Dim lbl1 As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("content"), Label)
        Dim lbl2 As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("url"), Label)
        content = lbl1.Text
        url = lbl2.Text
        Dim btn As LinkButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("glossary"), LinkButton)
        btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Response.Redirect('glossary.aspx?cont=' + content + 'url=' + url)return true;")
end su
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just modifiy below line of code because there is an error because of this only

there is no need of `respose.redirect` you need to redirect so you use javascript `location` object as i shown below

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location = 'glossary.aspx?cont=" + content + "&url=" + url + "';")
```

or

just set prostbackurl property of link button

```
btn.PostBackUrl= "glossary.aspx?cont=" + content + "&url=" + url ;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do this is to create a new event handler routine, pass the information to the Event Args and hook LinkButton btn to the event handler, then you can use the Response.Redirect.